# Problem with ImageButton(default yellow color)

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton that it changes it's background when we tap on it to a blue color.
However, when i tap on it i have the blue color as background but i have also a yellow one(the default that Android uses in any button).
[IMAGE LINK](http://imageshack.us/f/841/sansrehm.png/)
How can i solve this problem ?
Thank you for your help.

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/test"  android:layout_below="@id/button" android:src="@drawable/settings_xml"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:gravity="center"/>
```

This XML file(settings_xml.xml) is in /res/drawable-mdpi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/blue" /> <!-- pressed -->

     <item android:drawable="@drawable/stock" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Have i to put the XML file in ldpi and hdpi ?

Comment: can u paste the code where u have set imagebutton

Comment: @Sumant: sure. please see my edited first post.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Background Color of Image Button to Yellow,so whenever you tap on Image Button only yellow color will be displayed & not the Blue Color.

Comment: But i want to have the image changing its background color to blue when i tap on it.

Comment: since you are using selector so whenever you press the button it will set that Blue image to it .U can set background color of image button to transparent.So you are nt able to see yellow color.